# ¿Por qué en Colombia se usa "gonorrea" como insulto?

Tags: colombia, vulgaridades, insultos, vocabulario-médico

Estoy viendo la serie [*Narcos*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcos), orientada en la vida del narcotraficante colombiano Pablo Escobar (con un [acento no muy bueno](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/62016/4078), por cierto).

En un momento dado, se enfada muchísimo y se pone a insultar por teléfono:

> Hijueputa **gonorrea**, voy a matar a...

Lo de *hijueputa* en lugar de *hijo de puta* ya lo conocía. Lo que no recordaba es el uso de *gonorrea* en forma de insulto.

Si nos atenemos a la RAE, tenemos la definición:

> [**gonorrea**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JL8Nwds)
>   Del lat. mediev. gonorrhoea, y este del gr. γονόρροια gonórroia 'flujo seminal'.
>   1. f. Med. Enfermedad contagiosa de origen bacteriano, que se transmite por vía sexual y se caracteriza por un flujo purulento de la vagina o de la uretra.

Es decir, una enfermedad bastante dolorosa. ¿Será que la enfermedad estuvo muy extendida en su momento y que la frase completa sería *ojalá pilles gonorrea*? ¿Qué tan común es su uso actualmente y en los años ochenta?

Comment: El diccionario de americanismos [es tu amigo](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=gonorrea). :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque hoy se utiliza en toda Colombia se empezó a usar en la parte norte del país, en la ciudad de Medellin y en general en el Departamento de Antioquia, más o menos a mediados de los 90 por personas de barrios bajos, poca educación, criminales, asesinos.

Se asocia a la enfermedad y sus consecuencias desagradables.

Es una palabra que suena muy fuerte cuando se usa de manera despectiva o en estado de enojo o ira. También se utiliza en otros contextos como referencia a algo exagerado o entre amigos para enfatizar en algo negativo.

Comment: Me gustaría que _gonorrea dicho entre amigos_ no es para nada aceptable en una conversación formal, así se hablan entre gamines.

Answer (score 5):

Hoy en día la utilizan mucho, en especial las personas con baja formación educativa.

Además, gonorrea tiene varias connotaciones dependiendo del contexto. Una de ellas es de ofender al otro. En otros casos gonorrea se usa para decir que algo, algún evento o situación es extraordinario o fuera de lo común.

Ej.: Huy! ese accidente de tránsito fue una gonorrea.

Comment: mire este artículo para otras palabritas. http://www.pulzo.com/bogota/chimba-gonorrea-pirobo-fufurufa-y-otras-cositas-que-se-dicen-los-jovenes-bogotanos/329306

Comment: Caramba, en el artículo dicen que _gonorrea_ es sinónimo de _extraordinario_. Me pregunto: ¿podrías poner referencias sobre cuándo se popularizó esta expresión? ¿Empezó en personas con baja formación educativa y ahora se utiliza en más ámbitos? Yo solo la oí en películas y series de televisión. A todo esto, ¡bienvenido/a a [spanish.se]!

Comment: @fedorqui Aparte de insulto se utiliza como interjección con entonación exclamativa **"¡uy gon...! Qué accidente tan berraco"** pero mucho cuidado con su uso que es absolutamente vulgar e inapropiado en la mayoría situaciones. Es de uso común en las comunas de mi tierrita, pero suena terrible. Para que amplies el vocabulario de "narco" aclaro que sólo la usan los que nosotros llamamos "gamines", "ñeros" o "valijas".

Comment: @DGaleano ya me veo las tres siguientes preguntas de fedorqui: ¿Qué es un "gamín"? ¿Y un "ñero"? ¿Y un "valija"? :-)

Comment: @matabares Bienvenido. Quería anotar que aunque el link http://www.pulzo.com/bogota/chimba-gonorrea-pirobo-fufurufa-y-otras-cositas-que-se-dicen-los-jovenes-bogotanos/329306 es ilustrativo, **la mayoria** de las definiciones son erroneas o al menos **incompletas.** El escritor del artículo hizo muy poca investigación por lo que recomiendo a cualquiera que lea ese artículo contrastar las definiciones en otros sitios como por ejemplo http://www.asihablamos.com/

Comment: @DGaleano gracias por el comentario. Es tentador editar la respuesta para incluirlo o animarte a añadir una respuesta, pues es una pena que quedé aquí perdido entre los comentarios. Lo que aún no vi es cuándo se originó este uso, ¿te suena a ti?

Comment: Le dejo a @matabares la tarea de adicionar este y mi otro comentario a su respuesta. Y a propósito del origen aunque no tengo ninguna referencia que lo soporte pienso que es relativamente nuevo (creo que unos 10 años) y aunque hoy en día es muy usado por la "clase descendiente" de los narcos NO estaba generalizado en los 90's por lo tanto su uso en la serie es incorrecto como muchas cosas más de esa serie.

Comment: @DGaleano sobre su origen, [me han dicho](https://www.reddit.com/r/Colombia/comments/589un0/por_qu%C3%A9_en_colombia_se_usa_gonorrea_como_insulto/d8zaelz) que empezó hacia el 2002-2003. [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gonorrea%2Chijueputa&year_start=1900&year_end=2014&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgonorrea%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chijueputa%3B%2Cc0) da algo más de luz y se ve un ascenso en su uso desde 1970.