# Uso de "changón" en Colombia: significado, localización y origen

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, sustantivos, hispanoamérica, colombia

Este verano tuvimos un día como invitados en la casa de la playa a una familia originaria de Colombia. Como amante del lenguaje, esperaba ansioso el momento en el que pudiera aprender alguna palabra o expresión nueva, y este llegó de la siguiente forma: el padre de la familia estaba hablando de que al salir de Sevilla habían visto un control policial, y que hasta había un policía con un "changón".

Claro, ahí fue cuando miré con cara de estupefacción y pregunté qué era un changón, y me comentaron que en España nosotros le decíamos "escopeta". Busqué "changón" en el DLE y en el *Diccionario de Americanismos*, pero solo encontré una referencia en este último, y no era lo que esperaba:

> **[changón, -na.](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=chang%C3%B3n)**
>   adj. Ec. Referido a persona, de piernas robustas y bien formadas.

Tenía pues el significado en Ecuador pero seguía sin tener el de Colombia, que encontré [en otra página](http://www.asihablamos.com/www/significado/palabra/chang%C3%B3n):

> **Changón**
>
> en Colombia
>
> Escopeta, deriva de la forma errónea de pronunciar "shotgun".
>   *¡Voy a sacar el changón y voy a encender a plomo a ese pirobo!*

Así que confirmé el significado pero el origen me dejó sorprendido. ¿Podría alguien de Colombia confirmar este origen? ¿Es la palabra de uso general en todo el país, o solo en alguna región? ¿Se usa en algún otro país?

Comment: [Bogotalogo](http://www.bogotalogo.com/prensa/Bogotalogo-Version-Digital.pdf) no muestra ninguna entrada al respecto, pero sí menciona _changüita. Individuo peligroso y de mal actuar_. Supongo rápida la asociación entre este y la escopeta que pueda llevar.

Comment: Soy de Colombia y NUNCA había oído tal palabra. Debe ser muy particular de alguna zona en alguna ciudad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Igual que pasaba con [*gonorrea* como insulto](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/19457/1674), parece que esta es otra palabra del [*parlache*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parlache), esto es, una jerga propia de los barrios marginales de la ciudad de Medellín caracterizados por la ultraviolencia de los años 90 y probablemente extraída del visionado y emulación de películas tipo [*Scarface*](https://www.filmaffinity.com/es/film188896.html) (1983).

Una búsqueda de [*changón* en Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chang%C3%B3n&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchang%C3%B3n%3B%2Cc0) nos muestra cómo esta palabra empezó a usarse básicamente en los años 80 y creció espectacularmente en los 90, en los años de apogeo del [Cartel de Medellín](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartel_de_Medell%C3%ADn). Su descenso posterior y, a continuación, subida, lo explicaría por que se pudiera convertir en tabú durante los años posteriores a la caída de ese cartel y modo de vida, para luego pasar a ser popular a medida que se realizaran libros, películas y demás sobre esas gentes y épocas. Como observaste, ahora mismo es una palabra de uso más o menos común.

[image]

Revisando los resultados encontré un estudio prolijo al respecto llamado
[*Caracterización lexicológica y lexográfica del parlache para la elaboración de un diccionario*](http://www.tdx.cat/bitstream/handle/10803/8177/Tlscnde1de1.pdf).

En él aparece la definición:

> **changón**: Escopeta recortada, de fabricación casera, de un solo tiro.
>
> **changonazo**: Balazo

Luego leemos cosas como:

> Todas las palabras que se forman con el sufijo *-azo* están en relación con la violencia, el engaño o el consumo de droga: *changonazo*, *frutazo*, *pepazo*, *latazo*, hacen referencia al golpe que se recibe con un arma de fuego o blanca, en el caso de *latazo*.

Más adelante, en la página 184 habla de los *Anglicismos presentes en parlache* y muestra una lista en la que aparece *changón*:

> En el parlache los préstamos del inglés han sufrido, en su mayoría, una adaptación fonética y gráfica acorde con las normas de la lengua española. En primer término, escriben las palabras como las pronuncian, incluso con la tendencia a reemplazar la *y* por la *i*. Es más frecuente encontrar *bai* que *by*, a pesar de que en los colegios se enseña inglés.

---

Mirando otras referencias que aparecen en Google Ngram encuentro cosas como [*Asedios a la literatura de nuestra América Latina: García Márquez, Isaacs, De Silvestre, Sábato, García Marruz, Cardoso y Arreola*](https://books.google.es/books?id=UafsAAAAMAAJ) (2003), de Eliana Garzón Duarte:

> Vocablos como: changón, o sea el arma de fuego hecha artesanalmente, parcero o el amigo de bandidaje, fierro (el cual significa arma punzante o revóver) ubican al personaje en una escala de valores, cosificada por el poder del arrojo (...)

Luego en [*Verdugo de Verdugos*](https://books.google.es/books?id=RFu9AAAAIAAJ) (2002), de Fabio Restrepo:

> changón: escopeta con el cañón recortado (del inglés *short gun* [sic])
> <sub>Nótese que aquí habla de *short gun* y no de *shotgun*, que supuestamente es de donde realmente viene la palabra.</sub>

O en [*Crónicas a bordo de un taxi*](https://books.google.es/books?id=UtW3AAAAIAAJ) (2004), de Juan Carlos Díez contemplamos el uso entrecomillado de la expresión, señal de que aún se estaba incorporando al diccionario:

> ... y trataron de correr tras el sujeto del «changón». En ésas, varios taxistas se les echaron encima, los redujeron y comenzaron a golpearlos sin tregua.

Y así muchas referencias más, como por ejemplo la del libro [*Leidy Tabares, la niña que vendía rosas*](https://books.google.es/books?id=DO4uAAAAYAAJ), que hace referencia a la protagonista de la famosa película de [*La vendedora de rosas*](https://www.filmaffinity.com/es/film150105.html) (1998) que narra el submundo del Medellín de mediados de los 90.

Comment: Lo único que me parece equivocado es lo de "shoRt gun". La palabra con seguridad viene de lo que siempre vemos en el cine que es la típica [Escopeta Remington (pump-action) calibre 12](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escopeta) que en inglés se llama SHOTGUN [como esta](http://cdn3.volusion.com/7aztx.j6veq/v/vspfiles/photos/DML1061-2.jpg)

Comment: @DGaleano tremenda escopeta. Nótese que _short gun_ lo dice Fabio Restrepo en su _Verdugo de Verdugos_, probablemente llevado por la traducción de "arma corta" (concepto que se usa mucho en España). Edito para indicar este hecho. Por cierto, gracias por darme el sello de validez a la respuesta, esperaba con ansia que la leyeras tú para que pudieras detectar incorrecciones o imprecisiones. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Efectivamente, la palabra mal usada para la escopeta en mi país, es derivada de 'shotgun', por la mala pronunciación del ingles en la región.

Lo mismo pasa con *guachiman*, utilizada para referirse al vigilante, también derivada del inglés, 'watchman'.

Así somos en nuestro país, pero nos entendemos.