# ¿Cómo se originó la expresión "aquí hay gato encerrado"?

Tags: etimología, modismos

Según el diccionario, en el idioma español tenemos esta curiosa expresión:

> **[haber gato encerrado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=J0VULIX#AsY1OH5)**
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Haber causa o razón oculta o secreta, o manejos ocultos.

Esta expresión, además de tener ya más de dos siglos a sus espaldas, ha cruzado el charco puesto que el primer caso del CORDE es de Perú (y en España también se usa):

> *Pues aquí hai gato encerrado,
>
>   por que sin duda...*
>
> Pablo de Olavide y Jáuregui, "El celoso burlado. Zarzuela en un acto", 1764 (Perú).

Hay un caso anterior, pero no tengo claro de que haga alusión a este modismo. Para España encuentro en el mismo siglo este caso en la hemeroteca de la BNE:

> *Sabe Vm. lo que yo digo
>
>   que este Señor Alemano
>
>   debe de ser un bendito,
>
>   pues no vio el gato encerrado.*
>
> Correo de Madrid (ó de los ciegos). 25/3/1789, n.º 244, página 6.

En todo caso, en el DLE no entró hasta la edición de 1884. La pregunta es, ¿cómo se originó la expresión? ¿Qué tienen que ver los gatos encerrados con que haya causas o razones ocultas? ¿Tendrá algo que ver con la acepción de "gato" como "ladrón, ratero que hurta con astucia y engaño" o como "hombre sagaz, astuto", más que con el animal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pues aquí, y una vez más, [*El listo que todo lo sabe*](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/) nos lo resuelve en su blog. De [¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión ‘aquí hay gato encerrado’?](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/cual-es-el-origen-de-la-expresion-aqui-hay-gato-encerrado/):

> Para encontrar el origen de esta expresión debemos trasladarnos hasta los siglos XVI y XVII (también conocida esa época como Siglo de Oro) en el que se puso de moda llamar gato a la bolsa o talego en el que se guardaba el dinero.
>
> Era habitual llevar alguno de estos ‘gatos’ con sus respetivas monedas escondido entre las ropas  o guardado a buen recaudo en algún lugar de la casa, como remedio a los posibles hurtos.
>
> La víctima que estaba en el punto de mira de los rateros era observado para ver si tenía dinero y donde lo llevaba, por lo que la consigna que se daban entre sí, los amigos de lo ajeno, era diciendo que había allí había ‘gato encerrado’ o, lo que es lo mismo, una bolsa con dinero guardado y/o escondido.

Es curioso que la expresión aparezca a partir de 1884, pues como indica más arriba se popularizó en el Siglo de Oro. ¿Será porque pasó de sectores *gangsteriles* a populares poco a poco [como en otros casos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22104/1674)?

Sobre el uso de *gato* para nombrar a esta forma, en el blog sigue con:

> Lo que no se sabe con total seguridad es el porqué a este tipo de monederos se les dio el nombre de gato, habiendo quien indica que la razón era porque, originariamente, se confeccionaban con la piel de estos felinos y otros señalan que era el nombre coloquial utilizado en aquella época para llamar a los rateros que hurtaban con astucia y engaño (la RAE así lo recoge), puesto que estos ladrones tenían una habilidad que recordaba al comportamiento de los felinos.